# Дискорд-бот написанный на python не обнаруживает реакции

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

Вкратце у меня есть бот, который по команде копирует сообщение для опроса и пересылает его как embed, так же ставит на это сообщение 2 нужные реакции(галочка и крестик), исходное сообщение удаляет.
Так же по еще одной команде бот должен подсчитать реакции на сообщении и показать результат, также в embed, в зависимости от процентов.
Все бы ничего, все работает, но мне кажется, что бот не видит реакции вовсе, потому что он всегда показывает один результат вне зависимости от кол-ва реакций.
Я проверяла, есть ли у бота все нужные разрешения на сервере и пробовала выводить количество реакций видимых ботом в консоль(второе было безуспешно, поэтому я предполагаю, что бот просто вовсе не видит реакций)

Вот нужная часть кода:

```
@bot.command(name="poll")
async def echo(ctx, *, message):
  picture = None
  if len(ctx.message.attachments) > 0:
    # Read the first attachment as a file
    attachment = ctx.message.attachments[0]
    picture_content = await attachment.read()
    picture = discord.File(io.BytesIO(picture_content),
                           filename=attachment.filename)
  # Send the echoed message
  author_mention = ctx.author.mention
  new_embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Опрос",
    description=f"{author_mention} предлагает: \n{message}",
    color=0x5864ec)
  if picture:
    new_embed.set_image(url=f"attachment://{attachment.filename}")
  echoed_message = await ctx.send(embed=new_embed, file=picture)

  # Add reactions to the echoed message
  await echoed_message.add_reaction('✅')  # Check mark
  await echoed_message.add_reaction('❌')  # Cross

  # Delete the original message
  await ctx.message.delete()


@bot.command(name="result")
async def result(ctx):
  # Get the message that was replied to
  replied_message = ctx.message.reference.resolved
  if not isinstance(replied_message, discord.Message):
      await ctx.send("Не удалось найти сообщение, на которое был дан ответ.")
      return
    
  # Get the embed from the replied message
  message_embed = replied_message.embeds[0] if replied_message.embeds else None
  if message_embed is None or message_embed.description is None:
    await ctx.send("Не удалось найти сообщение, на которое был дан ответ.")
    return

  # Get the reaction counts
  check_mark_count = 0
  cross_count = 0
  for reaction in replied_message.reactions:
    if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
      check_mark_count = reaction.count
      print(check_mark_count)
    elif str(reaction.emoji) == '❌':
      cross_count = reaction.count
      print(cross_count)

  total_count = check_mark_count + cross_count

  # Calculate percentages
  if total_count > 0:
    check_mark_percentage = round((check_mark_count / total_count) * 100, 2)
    cross_percentage = round((cross_count / total_count) * 100, 2)
  else:
    check_mark_percentage = 0
    cross_percentage = 0

  # Determine the result
  if check_mark_percentage >= 60:
    result_text = "**Принято✅**"
  elif cross_percentage >= 50:
    result_text = "**Отказано❌**"
  else:
    result_text = "**‍⚖️Передано на дальнейшее рассмотрение модерацией‍⚖️**"

  # Create the result embed
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Результат опроса", color=0x5864ec)
  embed.add_field(name="Предложение:", value=message_embed.description, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Решение:", value=result_text, inline=False)

  # Send the result embed and delete the replied message
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await replied_message.delete()
  await ctx.message.delete()
```